# Can a freelance provide proof of work experience for a work visa in Schengen?

Tags: working-visas, schengen

I've been offered by my employer support for a move to Luxembourg - trying to gather the documents needed for my work visa. Under the "work permit" section of their [official immigration website](https://guichet.public.lu/en/citoyens/immigration/cas-specifiques/travailleur-frontalier-tiers/frontalier.html), it mentions that there's a need for a "diploma" or "professional qualification".

I've been working almost exclusively as a freelancer, which means I have very limited registered work history, and my university degree is irrelevant ( studied Civil engineering, working as a software developer ).

I was told that also 10 years of experience in my field ( which I have ) is enough, but I'm not sure how to provide proof for it that can be verified.

Is there anything I can do in this situation? I'm not sure if online certificates are of any value.

Comment: Adding the country where you have been working as a freelancer would make the answering of this question easier. In Germany you must register as a freelancer at the tax office.  A certificate can be issued by them for how long you have been doing this. Your employer should ask the Luxembourg authority what else they may require.